# How to apply style to selected text in CKEditor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to apply heading style (h1) to the selected text in CKEditor using JavaScript.

**Here is my function:**

```
        function applyStyle()
        {
            var selection = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection();
            if(selection.getType() == 2) //where 2 will be Text type
            {
                var style = new CKEDITOR.style({element: 'h1'});
                selection.applyStyle(style);
                style.checkActive(editor1.elementPath(), editor1);
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Select text to apply');
            }
        }
```

But I can't get the style applied on the selected text,

Kindly someone solve this

Thanks

Comment: And what have you checked? What does this code throws or do? I assume it must throw, because there's no `selection.applyStyle()` method.

Comment: Thanks Reinmar, it doesn't apply the style on the selected text in CKEditor, and for your reference here is the link:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style

Yes there is no selection.applystyle() method, I just tested whether its working on selection, can you suggest any way

Comment: Did you check the docs you linked? The answer to your question is in the first example there... ;/

Comment: I just tried as per the first example now, that also not applying the style on the text !

Comment: So please create a sample on which we'll be able what you do to correct your mistakes. We can't guess this.

Comment: Thanks Reinmar, I found a solution and I have posted below,  Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Its a cumbersome, but I found the solution for this ,see below

```
        function applystyle(tagName)
        {
            var selection = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection().getNative();
            var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
            var openTag = "<" + tagName + ">"; 
            var closeTag = "</" + tagName + ">"; 
            var html = openTag + selection + closeTag;
            var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( html, oEditor.document );
            oEditor.insertElement( newElement );
        }
```

I found the above code working well for me,

Thanks